# Convert subroutine to a function that can be used in a formula

Tags: arrays, vba, function, collections

I'm not very good with functions and was hoping someone could help convert this. I will be inserting the formula with a macro.

I have tried using formulas but run into issues when 2 or more matches are found.

The function will be inserted via macro like so.:

```
ws1.Range(Cells(x, spec), Cells(lRow, spec)).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR(MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""-"",RC[-3])+1,SEARCH(""-"",RC[-3],SEARCH(""-"",RC[-3])+1)-SEARCH(""-"",RC[-3])-1) = ""WP"",MID(RC[-3],SEARCH(""-"",RC[-3])+1,SEARCH(""-"",RC[-3],SEARCH(""-"",RC[-3])+1)-SEARCH(""-"",RC[-3])-1)=""DO""),""A15"",MID(RC[-3], FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(RC[-3],""-"",CHAR(1)," & aft & "))+1, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(RC[-3],""-"",CHAR(1)," & aft + 1 & ")) - FIND(CHAR" & _
        "(1),SUBSTITUTE(RC[-3],""-"",CHAR(1)," & aft & "))-1)),"""")" & ""

Sub Test()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim SrchStr As String
Dim myList, tbl As Object
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i, x As Integer
Dim val as String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry")

Set SrchRng = ws1.Range("A2:A30")
Set myList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
SrchStr = ws2.Range("AB7")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, SrchStr, cel.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        myList.Add cel.Value
        arr = myList.Toarray
        
    End If
Next cel

'######### Need to compare string length and keep the highest value ##########
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If IsNull(x) Or Len(arr(i)) > x Then
        x = Len(arr(i))
        val = arr(i)
    End If
Next i

ws2.Range("AE7") = val

Debug.Print x
Debug.Print a

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
Set SrchRng = Nothing
Set myList = Nothing
                     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED due to updated question.

A double loop will conduct a one to one search against the data to ensure that any duplicate entries are caught and correctly labelled.

Assuming there is some consistency with the formatting, this will look for the search criteria and `-` (ie: "A12UG-"). This will eliminate "A12UG" from triggering with "A12".

To call the function, assign the call to a variable. ie: `varName = updateAE()`

```
Function updateAE()
    Dim ws1: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry")
    Dim srchRng As Range, indexRng As Range, indexCel As Range, srchCel As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim indexLRow, srchLRow As Long
    
    indexLRow = ws1.Cells(ws2.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    srchLRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set indexRng = ws1.Range("A1:A" & indexLRow)
    Set srchRng = ws2.Range("AB3:AB" & srchLRow)
    count = 1
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each indexCel In indexRng
        For Each srchCel In srchRng
            If InStr(1, srchCel, indexCel & "-") > 0 And Len(indexCel) > 0 Then
                ws2.Range("AE" & count + 2) = indexCel
            End If
            count = count + 1
        Next srchCel
        count = 1
    Next indexCel
End Function
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have just updated my code to something very similar. See above. I was having an issue when writing the string value back to the worksheet so I created another variable instead. Now I need to write this as a function to be inserted in a formula.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I used a formula to find the nth "‐" before. However, this workbook will now be used company wide, and the formats vary so that formula is no longer an option.

Comment: The idea is to create a table with the specification codes(list) and search the string to see if it contains one of the list items. See the beginning of the code for the old formula.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how do I go about calling it? I'm not very good with functions!

Comment: @ Mech It works, but I'm getting weird behavior. `updateAE() = Range("AE7")`  works correctly, but I am getting "Run Time Error 424: Object Required". ''Range("AE7").Value = updateAE()'  fills a range with the correct values with no errors, and then some of the values disappear. Any idea what is causing that?